# Will the repo still work if I delete .git/lfs?

Tags: git, git-lfs

I have a copy of git repo that I only need for reference (to keep some local branches JIC). Can I delete the contents of `.git/lfs` and still expect commands like `git checkout local_feature; git push local_feature other/location` to work? Contents of .git/lsf takes too much disk space.

Comment: ...probably not, given that Git-LFS exists as a way for you to track those commits that *are* in fact too large?  But then that raises a huge question about how you set it up to begin with.  Are you talking about on your local machine or on a hosted, external system?

Comment: external system in this case. LFS seems to be an important part of the set up.

Comment: I'm scratching my head - LFS objects should still point to a remote server and only be downloaded when you need them.  Maybe the case is that you've got them all on your machine and there's just a lot of them with your initial checkout?  Maybe a bit more detail about how your setup is configured is in order.

Comment: Maybe the question should have been "How can I reduce the size of the folder?" https://www.mankier.com/1/git-lfs-prune

Comment: I was using the repo for a year now and the folder kept growing

Comment: `git lfs prune --force` seems to have done the trick

Answer (score 0):

You don't typically want to delete `.git/lfs`.  If the remote system where you're storing your LFS objects still exists and works, then you can simply run `git lfs prune`, which will delete unused objects that haven't been used recently, and they'll remain on the server.

If you want to delete everything that's safe to delete, you can use the `--force` option, which will get rid of everything that's on the server.  However, the reason that you don't want to delete `.git/lfs` is that it may contain objects which have yet to be pushed to the server, and if you did, then you'd lose data.

If your goal is to have a backup of what's on the server and maintain it even in case the server goes down, then you need the contents of `.git/lfs`, and you should even do `git lfs fetch --all` to make it complete.  Of course, that makes the local repository very large, since the goal is typically to offload that data to the server, but it is necessary for a backup.